# Supabase retrieve user

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, supabase, quasar-framework

I am logged in Supabase, when I click button on my webpage it shows me details of the account, that is signed in, so it works.
However I want show user email in html? How do I do that without calling any function? Just showing user.email in a

tag on a webpage? In supabase doc there is

```
const { data: { user } } = await supabase.auth.getUser()
```

So I need to put it in async function, no?
Thank you :)

everything I could

```
const { data: { user } } = await supabase.auth.getUser()
```

So I

Comment: await presumes that it's used in async function. It's unknown in which context you're using it, so nothing specific can be suggested. E.g. you can use await in Vue `script setup` syntax, but this forces you to use Suspense

Comment: @EstusFlask I use script setup. What is Suspense? Thank you

Comment: `await` in `script setup` is a shortcut for `async setup() { await .... }`. This requires this component to be used only inside <Suspense>. The docs are exhaustive on that, https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/suspense.html